# Scala if else behaviour

Tags: scala

I'm in my early scala hours and I expected the following two bits of code to behave the same but they do not. I was under the impression that "else" is optional.

Any ideas why? This is in a toString method (in a simple class representing rational numbers)

This works as expected, returns "1" (for 1/1):

```
if(numer == denom) {
  "1"
} else {
  numer + "/" + denom
}
```

This doesn't, returns "1/1":

```
if(numer == denom) {
  "1"
}

numer + "/" + denom
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `else` part is indeed optional, but the return value of a method is the value of the **last** expression in the method. So, when you don't put the else part in an actual `else` block, you always return that value. As a solution, you either use an `if/else` expression, which is the preferred way, or you use an actual `return` statement in the `if` statement.

```
// The return value of the method is the value of the if/else expression.
if (numer == denom) {
  "1"
} else {
  numer + "/" + denom
}
```

or

```
if (numer == denom) {
  return "1"
}

numer + "/" + denom
```

Comment: Yeap, I incorrectly assumed that `"1"` would be the last statement executed because it would immediately return and the last statement `numer + "/" + denom` wouldn't even be evaluated.

Comment: @Kaveh - You can use a `return` statement to force that behavior, but it's not the idiomatic Scala way to do things.